# Trying to group by a field with latest date in SQL where another field is equal

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

Hey I have run into a problem - I thought it would be easy with just group by but it was a little more when time is a factor in the game.

I'm trying to get all the records on different mainQuestion_id which can have duplicates with different timestamp (and id ofc). This should be filtered so I get those which are equal to an activationCode_id and not with a subquestion which is the field subQuestion_id

So lets say I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE surveys_answer
    (`id` int, `activationCode_id` int, `mainQuestion_id` int, `subQuestion_id` int,   `timestamp` int);

INSERT INTO surveys_answer
    (`id`,  `activationCode_id`, `mainQuestion_id`, `subQuestion_id`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
 (1, 1, 4, 0, 201313),
 (2, 1, 4, 0, 201314),
 (3, 2, 3, 1, 201315),
 (4, 2, 4, 0, 201316),
 (5, 1, 9, 1, 201317),
 (6, 1, 6, 0, 201318),
 (7, 1, 4, 1, 201319);
```

and I want the results which are `latest by time or id which have activationCode_id = 1 and where subQuestion_id = 0`

what I want is

```
2, 1, 4, 0, 201314

6, 1, 6, 0, 201318
```

I have been trying with group by, that misses (2, 1, 4, 0, 201314) and takes the first one (1, 1, 4, 0, 201313) which is not what I want

I thought this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM surveys_answer 
WHERE activationCode_id = 1
AND subQuestion_id = 0
group by mainQuestion_id
```

I have been trying to get this to work:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    surveys_answer a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  max(id) xx, mainQuestion_id
        FROM    surveys_answer 
        GROUP   BY mainQuestion_id
    ) b ON  a.mainQuestion_id = b.mainQuestion_id AND 
            a.id = b.xx AND a.activationCode_id = '1' AND a.subQuestion_id = 0
```

But this gives me zero results

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e1cd

Can some one help me out with this?

Comment: Can you include the exact results you are looking at, that is the list of all rows for result.

Comment: If you want latest by time, shouldn't the result have just 6, 1, 6, 0, 201318

Comment: Why and how you want to filter out the first record is still unclear to me. What is the business rule that you want to apply here?

Comment: @Adarsh no I want get every unique mainQuestion_id of latest date. 

2, 1, 4, 0, 201314  (got mainQuestion_id = 4)

6, 1, 6, 0, 201318  (got mainQuestion_id = 6)

Comment: So it's either `MAX(timestamp)` **or** `activationCode_id = 1 AND subQuestion_id = 0`, right?

Comment: @Rachcha The first record is not the latest record of mainQuestion_id = 4

Comment: Based on your SQLFiddle I added `MySQL` tag to your question.

Comment: @PM77-1 No it's MAX(timestamp) and activationCode_id = 1 AND subQuestion_id = 0.  if I'm not wrong, I need the latest record which has activationCode_id = 1 and  subQuestion_id = 0.  It sounds weird but i forgot to include one more field in the table which is data, the data can differ during time, and that's because it is important to get the record with the latest timestamp, even if all the other fields are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sa.*
FROM surveys_answer sa
WHERE timestamp = (
                   SELECT MAX(sa2.timestamp)
                   FROM surveys_answer sa2
                   WHERE sa2.activationCode_id = 1 AND sa2.subQuestion_id = 0 AND
                   sa2.mainQuestion_id = sa.mainQuestion_id
                  );
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e1cd/10)

Result based on your sample data:

```
| ID | ACTIVATIONCODE_ID | MAINQUESTION_ID | SUBQUESTION_ID | TIMESTAMP |
|----|-------------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------|
|  2 |                 1 |               4 |              0 |    201314 |
|  6 |                 1 |               6 |              0 |    201318 |
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this

```
SELECT surveys_answer .* , max(timestamp) as mx_time FROM surveys_answer 
WHERE activationCode_id = 1
AND subQuestion_id = 0
group by timestamp
```

Comment: Did not work 
"Can't group on 'mx_time': SELECT surveys_answer .* , max(timestamp) as mx_time FROM surveys_answer WHERE activationCode_id = 1 AND subQuestion_id = 0 group by mx_time"